# Select directories with date in their names from a date range

Tags: bash, date, directory, range, filenames

I'm creating a list of directories with the requested date range in their name.

Directories are all labeled `other_2019-07-18T00-00-00`. The **T** is messing me up!

Copied this loop from somewhere.

```
#!/bin/bash
curdate=$(date +%Y-%m-%d%H-%M-%S)
#
for o in other_*; do
    tmp=${o##other_}
      tmp=$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/T//') # clean up prefixes
      fdate=$(date -d "${tmp}")
      (( curdate < fdate )) && echo "$o"
done
```

I expect the final `echo` to include the path of all dir that match.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike `AWK`, Bash comparison operator `<` works only on numerical values.
Please try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
curdate=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

for o in other_*; do
    tmp=${o##other_}
    fdate=$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/[-T]//g')  # numeralization
    (( curdate < fdate )) && echo "$o"
done
```

As an alternative, you can compare epoch times:

```
#!/bin/bash

curdate=$(date +%s)

for o in other_*; do
    tmp=${o##other_}
    tmp=$(echo "$tmp" | sed 's/T/ /' | sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)$/\1:\2:\3/')
    fdate=$(date -d "$tmp" +%s)
    (( curdate < fdate )) && echo "$o"
done
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

### Instead of dropping `T`...

```
date -d 2019-03-23T00-06-28
date: invalid date '2019-03-23T00-06-28'
```

ok, but:

```
date -d 2019-03-23T00:06:28
Sat Mar 23 00:06:28 UTC 2019
```

So we have to replace last two dashes by `:`:

### As your question is tagged bash:

```
file="somepath/other_2019-07-18T00-00-00.extension"
time=${file#*other_}    # suppress from left until 'other_'
time=${time%.*}         # suppress extension
time=${time//-/:}       # replace all dash by a `:`
time=${time/:/-}        # replace 1nd `:` by a dash
time=${time/:/-}        # replace 1nd `:` by a dash (again)
date -d $time
Thu Jul 18 00:00:00 UTC 2019
```

This could by written:

```
printf -v now "%(%s)T" -1         # bashism for current date to variable $now
for file in somepath/other_*.ext ;do
    time=${file#*other_} time=${time%.*} time=${time//-/:}
    time=${time/:/-} time=${time/:/-}
    read fdate < <(date +%s -d $time)
    ((fdate > now)) && { echo $file: $((fdate - now)) ; }
done
```

## Reducing forks (to `date`) improve quickness:

for matching your sample, you could replace `for file in somepath/other_*.ext ;do` by `for file in other_*; do`. This must work quite same.

```
fifo=/tmp/fifo-date-$$
mkfifo $fifo
exec 5> >(exec stdbuf -o0 date -f - +%s >$fifo 2>&1)
echo now 1>&5
exec 6< $fifo
read -t 1 -u 6 now
rm $fifo
for file in otherdates/*.ext ; do
    time=${file#*other_} time=${time%.*} time=${time//-/:}
    time=${time/:/-} time=${time/:/-}
    echo $time 1>&5 && read -t 1 -u 6 fdate
    ((fdate > now)) && { 
        echo $file: $((fdate - now))
    }
done
exec 6>&-
exec 5>&-
```

In this, I run `date +%s` in background, with `-f` argument, `date` will interpret each incoming line, then answer *UNIX_TIME*. So `$now` is first read from `date` process, by:

```
echo now >&5 &&        # now, the string
    read -u 6 now      # read will populate `$now` variable
```

Nota, once *`fifo`* opened by both input and output, they could be deleted. It will remain for process until process close them.

Comment: Surely you are missing some semi-colons on lines commencing `time=...`?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No. There is no need of column in this kind of assignement. Try it!

Comment: Cool, that works - though I don't recall seeing it before nor understand why :-) I think that the first line `printf -v now ...` is specific to bash 4, by the way.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Care, I was wrong using slashes `/`! Answer corrected!

Answer (score 0):

there is no space between day and hour, which causes `date` not to be able to read the date. Try:

```
sed 's/T/ /'
```